# Tag Update -- Too Many, Too Much?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I have, as I have time, been adding content to the tags so they indicate appropriate info with what they are tagged to. Yesterday I tagged another five or six tags, but only one tag was updated. I'm not overly worried it, but **was just wondering if there was just a backup in the review process, or if I have exceeded the amount of work I can do in this area?** Mind you, I'm just trying to get some maintenance stuff done with the site to hopefully make it more appealing and useful to all. If I'm only allowed to do so much in this area, by all means I'll not do anymore.

Comment: Hi.. I rejected a bunch of edits from you as they were copied content from IMDB and other movie review websites.  We unfortunately cannot take copyrighted content like that. Sorry about that - its something that a lot of people do at first.

Comment: We certainly thank you for wanting to do maintenance on the site.

Comment: @iandotkelly No worries ... it's all a learning curve. How is the general formatting of what I've been doing? This seems to be a logical way of presenting it, but would like feedback.

Comment: The actual format and size of the entries were just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure exactly if the system has an auto-halt on editing activity but (and this is for your account specifically) if you go [**here**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/5391/paulster2?tab=activity) you can see all recent account activity and see what became of any suggested edits you have put forward.

More specifically it seems your last tag edits were rejected for being blatant copies of some other source (most likely wikipedia I assume)

We reject this on the excerpts because there is no way to ***attribute*** wiki as the source of the items.  It is ok to use it in the **Full Tag Wiki** but because the excerpts have such a limited character range it is much easier to just blanket deny.

For the excerpts we try to encourage **original** content as that is the summary that appears when a user is hovering over a tag.  It is meant to give a quick description of what the tag is about and used for.  If they choose to know more they can click on the tag for that.

Comment: I didn't realize if I clicked on the "suggested edits" it would show the comments and such (yes, I realized they were hyperlinks, just never looked). I appreciate the input and will take the comments to heart.